# In French must we always repeat the subject pronoun?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, sujet

In English it is not necessary to always repeat the subject pronoun before each verb:

> I would go to the market, look at the clothes, and then buy a coffee.

In French can one also leave out the subject pronoun?

> J'allais au marché, regardais des vêtements, puis achetais un café.

Comment: Yes, you can omit the subject. Using this tense sounds a bit weird though. I would opt either for the _passé composé_ or _passé simple_, since the _imparfait_ is often understood as continuous.

Answer (score 9):

**Neither are wrong,** you can either repeat it or omit it.

However, the version without the repeated pronoun will sound a lot more formal or literary. It's more something you'll read in a book. In casual oral context, it would sound strange, as the pronoun tends to always be repeated.

---

**> book version** (I switched to *passé simple* because your use of *imparfait* was a bit out of place here, like Jerry said in his insightful comment)

> J'allai au marché, regardai des vêtements, puis achetai un café.

**> a possible casual version** (same remark for *imparfait*, but *passé simple* is almost never employed orally, rather *passé composé*)

> Je suis allé au marché, j'ai regardé des fringues, et j'ai acheté un café.

Comment: I'm far from sure that the imparfait wasn't the correct translation: like _I would go_, it gives me the impression of an habit, while the passé simple or the passé composé would be better for a specific time. And like _I would go_, the sentence would feel more complete if it started with _Every Saturday_ or _Tous les samedi_.

Comment: You're probably right, I didn't pay enough attention to the *I would* part, which was in some way a minor aspect here, not the real question. Good point, though.

Comment: "Je suis allé au marché, j'ai regardé des fringues, et j'ai acheté un café." - I'd go for this.